# Prestashop Database Update - How to still have latest data from PROD?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.6

I have upgraded a prestashop system from version 1.4.x to latest 1.6.
Now this process had a lot of impacts on the codes, modules and our custom themes..etc

So we have been working on resolving all the issues for a week.

Now we are left with a problem: The database backup from PROD which was upgraded, now suffers from being "data outdated" as compared to the one on PROD right now.
What I mean is that during those 1.x weeks, the PROD database has been having new signups and new orders..etc.

**QUESTION**:
I want to have a suggestion on how I could update my "upgraded pre-prod database" for it to still have the latest transactions of PROD?
If I just do an import of the orders and clients from a date range and dump it, would this be the best option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If what you fix for the last week is not related to the database, just set the live site in maintenance mode, upgrade it, and then override all the files with the ones you fixed.

When I am upgrading client sites, I do it first locally and save in a separate folder all the changed files - the ones I needed to change after the upgrade in order the site to work as expected. Then do a live upgrade, and override the files with the ones from my folder.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are changes in the database for this upgrade and besides 1.6 do have changes in database from 1.4 to 1.6, is it?

Comment: The upgrade from 1.4 to 1.6 makes a lot of changes to the database.

Comment: If you have done changes to the Database, you had to save the quearies somewhere and to reapply them after the upgrade.